# SVM OpenCV example questions

Tags: java, opencv, svm

I have quenstions on the source code that follows below.
What i want to do is to train a SVM model with a set of images that are already classified. I have found an interesting example here on SO but have problem to understand what exactly is happening here. Now let's have a look:

```
public class Training{

protected static final String PATH_POSITIVE = "data/positivo/";
protected static final String PATH_NEGATIVE = "data/negativo/";
protected static final String XML = "data/test.xml";
protected static final String FILE_TEST = "data/negativo/1.jpg";

private static Mat trainingImages;
private static Mat trainingLabels;
private static Mat trainingData;
private static Mat classes;
private static CvSVM clasificador;

static {
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    trainingImages = new Mat();
    trainingLabels = new Mat();
    trainingData = new Mat();
    classes = new Mat();
}

public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
    trainPositive();
    trainNegative();
    train();
    test();
}

protected static void test() {
    Mat in = Highgui.imread( new File( FILE_TEST ).getAbsolutePath(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    clasificador.load( new File( XML ).getAbsolutePath() );
    System.out.println( clasificador );
    Mat out = new Mat();
    in.convertTo( out, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    out = out.reshape( 1, 1 );
    System.out.println( out );
    System.out.println( clasificador.predict( out ) );
}

protected static void train() {
    trainingImages.copyTo( trainingData );
    trainingData.convertTo( trainingData, CvType.CV_32FC1 );
    trainingLabels.copyTo( classes );
    CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_kernel_type( CvSVM.LINEAR );
    clasificador = new CvSVM( trainingData, classes, new Mat(), new Mat(), params );
    clasificador.save( XML );
}

protected static void trainPositive() {
    for ( File file : new File( PATH_POSITIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = getMat( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( img.reshape( 1, 1 ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.ones( new Size( 1, 1 ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }
}

protected static void trainNegative() {
    for ( File file : new File( PATH_NEGATIVE ).listFiles() ) {
        Mat img = getMat( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        trainingImages.push_back( img.reshape( 1, 1 ) );
        trainingLabels.push_back( Mat.zeros( new Size( 1, 1 ), CvType.CV_32FC1 ) );
    }
}

protected static Mat getMat( String path ) {
    Mat img = new Mat();
    Mat con = Highgui.imread( path, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    con.convertTo( img, CvType.CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0 );
    return img;
}

}
```

Basically i have two questions.

1. Is the line `protected static final String PATH_POSITIVE = "data/positivo/";` a path to all my positive **images**?If so can the path lead to a folder that contains Descriptors of each pictures that you create with SIFT or Surf in the beginning?Or is it necessary to have images in it? 

2. I don't want to work with the whole picture. How can i define an area which is interesting for me. And which is essential for all pictures.(Training and test) For example the under half of each picture without cutting it.

Comment: 1) Yes, is the folder of images. You can put there your descriptor matrices instead of images, but you need to change `getMat` to load those data. 2) Have a look at [submat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) method

Comment: Would you please make an example how to create a submat of the second half of the picture and put the data from the source matrix inside it. If you write it as an answer, i will like it. The first point too.

Comment: You can do that using a combination of `copyTo` and `submat`. Have a look on Google or SO for an example, I can't provide Java code :D

Comment: :D. I'm not sure if copyTo is the right one. Submatrix may be build be reference

Comment: Exactly, and copying data into the submatrix will modify the original matrix (_put data from the source matrix inside it_)